# Deploying from Appveyor to Nuget only on changes in a particular folder

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, nuget, appveyor

I have a .NET Core project that is auto-built in Appveyor and deployed to Nuget. By default, every successful build causes a new Nuget release.

However, there are many cases when a new release is meaningless because the library's actual code has not changed:

- Readme updated
- Unit tests added
- Appveyor configuration changed
- Other cases

It is possible to configure the build so that Nuget publishing only runs if there are changes in the actual code (for example, in folder `X`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options.

- [Commit filtering](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/filtering-commits/#include-commits-2). Note that with it the whole build, not just deployment will be skipped if nothing in folder `x` changed. You may need a build without deployment at least when unit tests added. As a workaround consider adding separate AppVeyor project which will build and deploy only if folder `x` changed and keep current project to build every time, but not deploy
- Inspect changed files with script. Please check [this sample](https://gist.github.com/IlyaFinkelshteyn/1deffbd1f73dee326aceb5de88524d6a) on how to check those files if you use GitHub. So if you see that files in folder `x` changed, you can set some custom environment variable (lets say you call it `deploy_nuget`) to `true`, and use it with a [conditional deployment](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/#conditional-deployment).